# Passing values to Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arguments, mouseover

here is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//if(event.type == 'mouseenter') { 

$(".big2box").mouseover(function() {


    var val1='.big2box';
    var val2='.small2box';

});

$(".big0box").mouseover(function() {


    var val1='.big0box';
    var val2='.small0box';

});

     $(val1 +","+ val2).hover(function(){
     alert(val1+val2)
     });`
```

now iam trying to pass the specific values for `val1,val2` if an user mouseover on `specific div`
      `

iam aware we can do this by passing through function but not sure how it works in jquery.is there anyone who can help me to fix this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var val1 = null;
var val2 = null;

$(".big2box").mouseover(function() {
    if (val1 != null && val2 != null){
        $(val1 +","+ val2).off("hover");
    }

    val1='.big2box';
    val2='.small2box';
    $(val1 +","+ val2).on("hover",function(){
       alert(val1+val2)
    });
});

$(".big0box").mouseover(function() {
    if (val1 != null && val2 != null){
        $(val1 +","+ val2).off("hover");
    }

    val1='.big0box';
    val2='.small0box';

    $(val1 +","+ val2).on("hover",function(){
       alert(val1+val2)
    });
});
```

Another way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//if(event.type == 'mouseenter') { 
var val1= null;
var val2= null;

$(".big2box").mouseover(function() {

val1='big2box';
val2='small2box';

});

$(".big0box").mouseover(function() {

val1='big0box';
val2='small0box';

});

     $(".big2box,.small2box,.big0box,.small0box").hover(function(){
         if ($(this).hasClass(val1) || $(this).hasClass(val2)){
            alert(val1+val2);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... i have to put `    $(val1 +","+ val2).hover(function(){
       alert(val1+val2)
    });`  in one function... i can not write it on each mouse over... i just need to pass variable to to hover depending on mouse over...

Comment: your answer is similar to what i was looking, slight edit can fix my probelm,,, Thanks @Khanh To